# Pagination on every page in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, pdf-generation

I want 8 entries to be displayed on each printing page..but my problem is i am getting only 8 entires on the first page but i am having 18 entries on my database...When i click on second page it displaying undefined variable error..the first page works fine..below i have attached the error screenshot(when i click on second page).....

[image]Model:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mdl_pagination extends CI_Model {

 function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
 }

 function countcountry(){
  $Search = $this->input->post('Search');
 $this->db->where('billno', $Search);
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('salesitem');
   $this->db->join('salesbill', 'salesbill.no = salesitem.billno','left outer');
   $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = salesbill.partyname','left outer');
   $this->db->join('itemmaster','itemmaster.itcode = salesitem.Product_Code','left outer');
$query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->num_rows();           // return total number of country
 }

 function getcountries($limit,$offset){
     $Search = $this->input->post('Search');
 $this->db->where('billno', $Search);
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('salesitem');
   $this->db->join('salesbill', 'salesbill.no = salesitem.billno','left outer');
   $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = salesbill.partyname','left outer');
   $this->db->join('itemmaster','itemmaster.itcode = salesitem.Product_Code','left outer');
   $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
$this->db->limit(8, $offset);
$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        return $query; 
 }

}
```

Controller code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pagination extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('mdl_pagination');
  $this->load->library('table');
  $this->load->helper("url");
 }

 public function country($page=null)
 {
  $this->load->library('pagination');

  $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Yuva1/pagination/country/';    // url of the page
  $config['total_rows'] = $this->mdl_pagination->countcountry(); //get total number of records 
  $config['per_page'] = 8; 
   // define how many records on page
  $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

  $this->pagination->initialize($config);
   $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

  $query = $this->mdl_pagination->getcountries($config['per_page'],$page);
  $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $data['query'] = $query;
  $this->load->view('Inventory/Bill_Print1', $data);
 }

}
```

And i also have one doubt is there is any possibility to make only 8 entries on each page(without link) except pagination concept because i want it implement in printing bill

Answer (score 0):

*You currently using an array in offset also you have `$page` so you don't need to define URI segment. easily use.
edit your county function like this.*

```
public function country($page=0)
{
  $this->load->library('pagination');

  $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Yuva1/pagination/country/';    // url of the page
  $config['total_rows'] = $this->mdl_pagination->countcountry(); //get total number of records 
  $config['per_page'] = 8; 
  $config['cur_tag_open']  = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
  $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
  $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
  $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
  $this->pagination->initialize($config);    
  $query = $this->mdl_pagination->getcountries(8,$page);
  $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
  $data['query'] = $query;
  $this->load->view('Inventory/Bill_Print1', $data);
 }
```

Comment: show me the error. also, I edited my answer try that.

Comment: My problem is i am getting undefined variable error(refer screenshot) on my post when i am clicked 2 page..I tried your code..it does not give any link and it's just displaying  8 entries on first page..but i have 18 entries on my database...And i want 1 to 8 on page 1 9 to 17 on page 2 like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183290/discussion-between-esakkichandra-and-abdulahmad-matin).